# NSAsynchronousFetchRequest possible memory leak

Tags: swift, core-data, memory-leaks, swift3, instruments

**PROBLEM:** Analyzing an iOS app with xcode instruments it appears to be a small but crucial (the snippet is indirectly executed all through the project) memory leak.

**DESRCIPTION:** We don't make any use of Entities references and follow the typical apple suggested core data object context stack

Here is a screenshot of instruments showing an apparent leak due to `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` maintaining a mutual indirect reference to a `NSFetchResult`

[image]

Here is the code snippet triggering the leak (removeing all the non-neccessary code, even the [weak self] still doesn't change it) according to *Instruments*

```
let anEntityFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: AnEntity.entityName)

let asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: rangeQuantityFetch) { (asynchronousFetchResult) -> Void in
    //
}

do {
    // commenting out the execute there is no leak anymore
    _ = try managedObjectContext.execute(asyncFetchRequest)

} catch {
}
```

The same thing happens enabling compile optimization flags.

**QUESTION:** Is there a possibility that it is only an Instruments or xcode bug? Or that it is a known core data issue? Or any useful hint to address me to the problem source would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an **issue** with the core data object contexts stack. In the configuration we have the a main context having as parent a write context that has the actual persistence coordinator.
According to [memory-leak-on-nspredicate-that-used-in-fetch-request-to-fetch-nsmanagedobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272197/memory-leak-on-nspredicate-that-used-in-fetch-request-to-fetch-nsmanagedobject) the problem is with the main context haveing a parent.

To **solve** this either

- change the core data stack as pointed in the answer
- or (seems to
  work but is not a clean solution) extend the `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` to set to nil the `request` property
  after the completion block is called (this way the reference cycle is
  broken and resources can be deallocated by ARC).

Comment: I am seeing this same issue and cannot change my entire core data stack right now. Can you explain your second solution? When I extend NSAsynchronousFetchRequest the 'fetchRequest' property is get-only and I cannot set it to nil.

Comment: A bit late i guess, but for future readers: this solution does not work anymore and seems to not to be needed with ios14.